# How to assign background color through JS (same as IMG bg), depending on database value (sex)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, if-statement

**Visualisation:**

```
[IMG]+[HIDDEN INPUT]-—-[TEXT]-—-[ICON]
[IMG]+[HIDDEN INPUT]-—-[TEXT]-—-[ICON]
[IMG]+[HIDDEN INPUT]-—-[TEXT]-—-[ICON]
```

(For each user)

I want to give the icon on the right the same background color as the IMG on the left.
The image is an SVG avatar from Dicebear.

The idea is if a user is male (`sex===M`), their avatar has a blue background, and if female; a pink one.
I'm trying to give the icon on the right of the text the *same* background color.

I've tried doing it through a hidden input with their gender as the value (`M, F, O`), and running that through a Javascript function on pageload;

```
    function recolor() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-icon");

    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      let sex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
      let background;
      if (sex === "M") {
          background = "blue";
      }
      else if (sex === "F") {
          background = "pink";
      }
      else {
          background = "yellow";
      }
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = background;
    }
  }
```

This got me varying results, from all icons pulling the background from the last else, to them just pulling it from their standard in CSS (which shouldn't happen, as DOM manipulation is supposed to overrule that, right?)

I'm not that good with Javascript yet, and have tried multiple different versions of this here code, all leading to different results.

Chance is quite high that I'm glancing over something incredibly simple. Any help is welcome!

---

Edit (the HTML):

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/avataaars/profile.svg?<?php echo $user->pf_settings ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="sex" id="sex" value="<?php echo $user->sex ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
   <p><?php echo $user->text; ?></p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <i class="fa fa-icon"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you share with us a codeSandbox or something more relevant ? I am having issue to understand what kind of result do you have and what do you want to do

Comment: Your code logic seems fine but we'd need the HTML as well to see what elements and values you are actually working with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @ScottMarcus Apologies, HTML added at the bottom.

Comment: And what colour should non-binary take? Were I you I'd raise the issue that this is currently a (potentially) exclusive system, and may need to be explored further to allow your users to determine their own gender (and colour) and also enable that chosen gender to be hidden. This is, of course, entirely separate, and tangential, to the problem you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lookup table and loop over the inputs

```js
const colors = {
  "M": "blue",
  "F": "pink",
  "O": "yellow"
};
const genders = document.querySelectorAll("[name=gender]");
genders.forEach(gender => {
  const color = colors[gender.value] || colors.O;
  gender.closest("div.container").querySelector(".fa-icon").style.backgroundColor = color;
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/avataaars/profile.svg">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="M">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-icon">Avatar</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/avataaars/profile.svg">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="O">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-icon">Avatar</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/avataaars/profile.svg">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="Something else">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-icon">Avatar</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS selector,

```
#sex[value='M'] ~ .fa-icon { background-color: green; }
#sex[value='F'] ~ .fa-icon { background-color: red; }
#sex[value='O'] ~ .fa-icon { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: `#sex[id='M']`? How can the `id` be both `sex` and `M`?

Comment: Sorry, @Kaiido. It should be value. It has been updated.